# GGPlot2: Errorbars grouped by condition

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using those data:

```
condition <- c('control', 'control', 'causal', 'causal') # grouping condition
shift <- c('first', 'second') # subgrouping condition
means <- c(-30, 60, -20, 40) # means per group
se <- c(6, 10, 7, 9) # Standard errors per group
plotdata2 <- data.frame(condition, shift, means, se)
```

i would like to plot error bars in the following plot:

```
ggplot(plotdata2, aes(x=condition, y=means, fill=shift)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width = .6) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

However, using

```
ggplot(plotdata2, aes(x=condition, y=means, fill=shift)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width = .6) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = min(se)-0.5, ymin=max(se)+0.5))
```

[image]

does not work because the error bars are taking the global ymax and ymin of SE. How can I make two different error bars using the respective condition's min(se) and max(se)?

I do not have the original data; I can therefore only use this summary.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply forgetting to add the `se` to the `y = means`.

```
ggplot(plotdata2, aes(x=condition, y=means, fill=shift)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width = 0.6) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = means - se - 0.5, ymin = means + se + 0.5), width = 0.6) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]